# How to set shell prompt?

Tags: bash, prompt

My shell prompt appears to have changed. I am not sure what I did to cause it.

How it appears now:

```
bash-4.2$
```

How I want it to appear:

```
robinhood@ubuntu$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt is configured by startup files, `/etc/profile` or per-user in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) explains which files are used depending on how bash is invoked.

[Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt) has examples with default and custom prompts. You possibly want to restore the default Ubuntu prompt to `~/.bashrc` (assuming it got deleted):

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

If you do not want current working directory in the prompt, remove `\w`.